# Accessing variable out completion block

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

How can i access the employee value outside the completion block in order to use it anywhere in the `ViewController`

```
extension TabsParentViewController{
    class func checkCreateTabPermission(completion: @escaping PermCompletionWithCancel){
        RRS.s.permissionService.checkForPermission(.createTab, completion: { (pass, employee, cancel) in
            if !cancel {
                ActivityLogsBuilder.logActivity(forEmployee: employee, module: .tabs, action: ActivityLogsBuilder.action(from: LogAction.createTab, authorized: pass))
            }
            completion(pass, employee, cancel)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly makes unable to do it?

Comment: for exaple i have a function that takes an employee input and called somewhere out of the above function like so 
x.func(employee: "here i need to pass the completion employee result")
but actually how to access the employee result ?

Comment: i can only access the employee inside the closure itself but i need it outside

Comment: It's clear that `PermCompletionWithCancel` it a typealias which contains the employee as one of its parameters; Have you tried to call `checkCreateTabPermission`? How it looks?

Comment: yes , it is typealias PermCompletionWithCancel = ((Bool, Employee?, Bool) -> Void)

Comment: if i call checkCreateTabPermission again it will call the function again which is already called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, calling `checkCreateTabPermission` as:

```
checkCreateTabPermission { pass, employee, cancel in
    // here you can use the `employee`
}
```

should make you able to access the returned `employee`. So, you could call the needed method inside the `completion` of `checkCreateTabPermission`:

```
checkCreateTabPermission { pass, employee, cancel in
    myMethod(employee: employee)
}
```

Or if you want to access the employee outside of the `completion`, you could declare a variable (which is `nil` by default) to hold its value once it returned:

```
var myEmployee: Employee?

checkCreateTabPermission { [weak self] pass, employee, cancel in
    self?.myEmployee = employee
}

// you could use `myEmployee` here, but you have to make sure its not nil,
// in other words, `checkCreateTabPermission` has been called and retrieved one.
if let myUnwrappedEmployee = myEmployee {
    // use `myUnwrappedEmployee`...
}
```